# How to get only email address using everyauth in node.js

Tags: node.js, email, oauth, everyauth

I am developing web application using node.js, and I want to give fetcher to my user to import contacts from various email services (eg. gmail, facebook, linkedin etc..). 
For that I am using everyauth module to connect these services. I am setting successfull response for those service on my server. Now I would like to parse it and get all emails and store it in my database. Now my question is how to get all emails with firstname, lastname or other information from that response on my service side method?

thanks